# How to select rows if the date between is in current month

Tags: sql

I have a table that has two fields `FromDate`, and `ToDate`, and lots of data in it.
What I want is to get the rows If current month is midst of these fromdate and todate.

Eg: 
(1) `FromDate = 20/Dec/2013 & ToDate = 15/Feb/2014`, so it should appear if `Current Month (Jan 2014)` is selected.

(2) If `FromDate = 05/Jan/2014 & ToDate = 10/Jan/2014`, this also should appear if current month is selected.

Can anybody give me a query that returns a result like this?

Edit: I want to check for a month, Not a Date. Eg: To get all rows for Jan 2014 If the date between fromdate and todate lies  in.

Comment: Is it not just as simple as SELECT [values] FROM [Table] WHERE GetDate() BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate

Comment: What database you're woking on?

Comment: SQL,,, 
I dont want to check a date,,, 
I want select rows for a month Eg: Getting all rows For Jan 2014 If a customer staying date lies between this month,,,,

Comment: sql is not a database. Do you mean sql-server 2008 ?

Comment: Have you tried anythig yet??

Comment: Nop... I didnt get a clue yet...
Its a Hotel Management to retrieve the list of people who stayed this month,,, 
Maybe he started last month and will stay until 3 months...

Comment: Yep... I found it last.,., It was so simple... Thanks all friends who helped me ...

Comment: SELECT * FROM     RM_UserBookingData
WHERE     (FromDate< MAX_DATE_OF_THIS_MONTH) AND (ToDate> MIN_DATE_OF_THIS_MONTH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @selectedmonth datetime = current_timestamp

select * from yourtable
where FromDate < dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, @selectedmonth), 1)
and  ToDate > dateadd(m, datediff(m, 0, @selectedmonth), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
select sysdate as currentDate from dual;

    Select * from [table name] 
    where currentDate between fromDate and ToDate;
```

Comment: Not for a date, for a Month :(